# how to stop the fadein repeating over multiple hovers

Tags: jquery

I currently have this code below:

```
$("ol#homePortfolio li img").fadeTo("slow", 1.0);

$("ol#homePortfolio li img").hover(
    function() {
        $("ol#homePortfolio li img").fadeTo("slow", 0.8); 
    }, 
    function() {
        $("ol#homePortfolio li img").fadeTo("slow", 1.0); 
    }
);
```

However, when I hover over the image multiple times the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` keeps on carrying on, how can I apply the stop so it only happens once?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [`stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function. (jquery.com is having issues today, here's a link to [Google's cached copy](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:GcYE4fupV-kJ:api.jquery.com/stop/%20api%20jquery%20stop&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&source=www.google.co.uk).) `stop` stops any animation currently in progress.

Just call it prior to starting an animation, to stop any previous animation on that element:

```
$("ol#homePortfolio li img").stop().fadeTo("slow", 0.8);
//                           ^----
```

You'll want to play with it a bit (I don't do many animations that might overlap), stopping some animations in the middle might mean you need to be sure to reset the element to a known state. Or alternately, use the `jumpToEnd` flag:

```
$("ol#homePortfolio li img").stop(false, true).fadeTo("slow", 0.8);
//                                ^      ^-- true = jump to the end of the animation
//                                |--------- false = don't clear the queue (you may
//                                           want true here, to clear it)
```

Comment: Yeah I thought so but I dont know how to implement it as I am still quite new to jquery

Answer (score 5):

Meh, I don't like stop() that much, it's a bit inneficient.

You should put this before your first fadeTo in the hover function :
`.filter(":not(:animated)")`

Comment: I just looked at the implementation of `stop` and it looked pretty efficient to me. (I mean, a fair bit of what jQuery doesn't isn't all that efficient, because you're trading efficiency for convenience, compactness, and expressiveness. It doesn't seem *particularly* inefficient.) What kinds of inefficiencies are you talking about? And particularly relative to applying a nested filter... (Not being difficult, genuine question.)

Comment: Basically, it prevents the animation from completing a full cycle, meaning there's a risk it'll look jerky depending on how you use your mouse; the filter does not. Read up [here](http://css-tricks.com/full-jquery-animations/)

Comment: That's not efficiency, then, that's about UX. Fair 'nuff, I try to avoid doing anything resembling overlapping animations anyway, because too much going on tends to be a bad thing whether jerky or otherwise... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, maybe efficiency wasn't the right word then. I'm French :-P

Answer (score 3):

I use

```
.stop()
```

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

I used `.filter(":not(:animated)")`. it works fine for me, but `.stop()` does not.
When I used `.stop()` multiple times hovering over mouse on link animations freezes in a middle of `fadeIn` or `fadeOut`. I suggest using `.filter()` in such situations.